# Play sound when number changes in external file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, mp3, audio

**Play mp3 sound** if number in external file on server change from 0 to 1 is this possible that flash reads external file changes ever 2 minutes

Comment: Could you explain more precisely your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're really asking about here has nothing to do with playing an mp3, but rather how to poll a file hosted on a server.

First, you'd want some kind of a timer. When that timer goes off, you load the file using a `URLLoader`. You then check the contents of the loader to see if the value has changed to 1:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var currentValue:int = 0;
var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url_of_your_file");
fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
// you prbably also want to handle errors (if the file doesn't exist)

var pollTimer:Timer = new Timer(120000); // 120,000 milliseconds = 2 minutes
pollTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, pollFile);

pollFile(null); // initial call to pollFile
pollTimer.start(); // subsequent calls to pollFile

function pollFile(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    fileLoader.load(fileRequest);
}

function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    if(!currentValue && int(fileLoader.data) == 1)
    {
        // the value of the file has changed from 0 to 1 
        // execute your mp3 playing code here
    }
    currentValue = int(fileLoader.data);
}
```

**EDIT**: Reading your comments, it's possible that your request is getting cached and therefore returning the same value every time. There is a bit of a trick to requesting non-cached data:

```
// when you create your request, add a query string (noCache) that will change every time.
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url_of_your_file?noCache=" + new Date().time);

function pollFile(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // update the value of noCache every time you load the request
    fileRequest.url = fileRequest.url.split("?")[0] + "?noCache=" + new Date().time;
    fileLoader.load(fileRequest);
}
```

Comment: it works but only one time

Comment: when changing nothings happened i tried to change time to 10 seconds but nothing hapens

Comment: I've edited the answer, please let me know if you're still having issues.